# How to implement kafka as same as ActiveMQ queue?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

If we have consumer1 and consumer2  for an ActiveMQ queue then the same message will not be delivered to both consumers. It will deliver like some set of messages to consumer1 and another set of messages to consumer2.  How we will do the same with apache Kafka in Spring?

Comment: Put both consumers into the same consumer group.

Comment: Hm. You probably need to learn more what is MVC - fully not related to this Kafka matter...

Comment: @ArtemBilan  I mentioned Spring Framework because I want to know specifically the configuration with spring framework accidentally I added MVC there. If you are aware of how to config the Kafka with spring as mentioned in the question give a hint.

Comment: @daniu Thanks Let me try as you said

Answer (score 0):

Please, learn more what is Apache Kafka and how its offset management works. What you are asking is just not possible with such an architecture: we must preserve an order for offset therefore only one consumer in a group going to process all the messages from the same partition.

You kinda can have two consumers in the same group, two partitions in the same topic, but only one consumer is going to read from one partition. You'll never get a round-robin behavior like in ActiveMQ queue.